# the concept of open subsets in principle of mathematical analysis remark2.29

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

My understandings: a set $E$ is said to be an open subsets of $X$ , if for every point $p$ in $E$,and given a positive number $r$, if a point q satisfy Id(p,q)

I really can't find an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not given $r$, you are suppose to show that for all element, you can find such element $r$.

Consider $(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Given $x\in (0,1)$, we can choose $r$ to be $\min(x, 1-x)$.